# malloc in an embedded system without an operating system

Tags: c, embedded, memory-management

This query is regarding allocation of memory using `malloc`.

Generally what we say is `malloc` allocates memory from heap.

Now say I have a  plain embedded system(No operating system), I have normal program loaded where I do `malloc` in my program.

In this case where is the memory allocated from ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

malloc() is a function that is usually implemented by the runtime-library. You are right, if you are running on top of an operating system, then malloc will sometimes (but not every time) trigger a system-call that makes the OS map some memory into your program's address space.

If your program runs without an operating system, then you can think of your program as **being** the operating system. You have access to all addresses, meaning you can just assign an address to a pointer, then de-reference that pointer to read/write.

Of course you have to make sure that not other parts of your program just use the same memory, so you write your own memory-manager:

To put it simply you can set-aside a range of addresses which your **"memory-manager"** uses to store which address-ranges are already in use (the datastructures stored in there can be as easy as a linked list or much much more complex). Then you will write a function and call it e.g. **malloc()** which forms the functional part of your memory-manager. It looks into the mentioned datastructure to find an address of ranges that is as long as the argument specifies and return a pointer to it.

Now, if every function in your program calls your malloc() instead of randomly writing into custom addresses you've done the first step. You can write a **free()**-function which will look for the pointer it is given in the mentioned datastructure, and adapts the datastructure (in the naive linked-list it would merge two links).

Comment: Didn't answer the real question: Where does the dynamically allocaded memory goes. It goes to the heap. Where is the heap? It is in an address range configured by the linker script.

Comment: @fanl Your question is different from Leo Messi's question. Did you -1 this answer? Please undo. If you open your own question I will try to answer it.

Comment: This was a wonderful thought experiment, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The only real answer is "Wherever your compiler/library-implementation puts it".

In the embedded system I use, there is no heap, since we haven't written one.

Comment: +1 and when you enable optimizations, the compiler may choose the stack when it can determine that the allocation is local (e.g. to the function).

Comment: Ok, true, but not very helpful either.

Answer (score 4):

From the heap as you say.  The difference is that the heap is not provided by the OS.  Your application's linker script will no doubt include an allocation for the heap.  The run-time library will manage this.

In the case of the [Newlib](http://sourceware.org/newlib/) C library often used in GCC based embedded systems not running an OS or at least not running Linux, the library has a stub [syscall](http://sourceware.org/newlib/) function called sbrk().  It is the respnsibility of the developer to implement sbrk(), which must provide more memory the the heap manager on request.  Typically it merely increments a pointer and returns a pointer to the start of the new block, thereafter the library's heap manager manages and maintains the new block which may or may not be contiguous with previous blocks.  The previous link includes an example implementation.